# What is the relationship between iproute2 and DHCP?

Tags: networking, dhcp, iproute2

If I use DHCP on my router it allows me not to care about static routes? Do I need to use iproute2 toolset only when setting static routes without DHCP configured?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.